# Drupal WYSIWYG editor

Tags: 7

I want to have a simple WYSIWYG when people add comments and when people edit the body of a basic page.

Something that looks like this:
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [ckEditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor), it works fine.

[image: ckeditor]

You can also install [wysiwyg](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) which manage many wysiwyg editor like ckeditor and others.
You can try [simple editor](http://drupal.org/project/seditor) too.

Comment: I got ckeditor working but I really want it for the insert image functionality but it only lets you insert a link and not upload an image. Do you know how to get that functionality in a wysiwyg?

Comment: You CAN use it with [imce](http://drupal.org/project/imce)if you want To upload images

Comment: Perfect. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [WYSIWYG](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module. This will allows you to install severals other WYSIWYG, like CKEditor, TinyMCE, etc..

Once you've done it, you can create a new filter format and a new profile with your settings (so you can show only the buttons you want). The you just have to set that format into the fields. For that I think [Better Format](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats) module will help you.

Comment: I got ckeditor working but I really want it for the insert image functionality but it only lets you insert a link and not upload an image. Do you know how to get that functionality in a wysiwyg?